# How can I install my project from source with Buildout?

Tags: python, deployment, buildout

I want to use [Buildout](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout) to install my [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute)-based project and its dependencies to an isolated environment. My project should be installed directly from the source tree (a local Git repository), and is not registered with PyPI. How do I accomplish this?

**Edit:**

Thanks to M. Pieters I was able to suss out what to do. I'm posting my `buildout.cfg` for reference:

```
[buildout]
develop = .
parts = fbt

[fbt]
recipe = z3c.recipe.scripts
eggs = BuildTools
```

Although I didn't need it right now, knowledge of [mr.developer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer) could definitely come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have 3 options, depending on where you want your buildout configuration to live and what options you have to check out your git repository.

Note that as far as Python is concerned, the resulting egg is exactly the same. The only difference between a development egg and a "normal" egg is that a development egg overrides any version requirements set elsewhere for that egg; it will be used regardless of what other versions of the egg are found elsewhere.

## Inside the development repository

Just use the `develop` option. This creates a development egg, which is just the same as a normal egg but without a version check, nothing more, nothing less.

Your buildout simply needs to list the current directory (where setup.py lives) as the development egg:

```
[buildout]
develop = .
```

## In a different location

You'll need to be able to reach the git repository for this to create a new checkout. Use [mr.developer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer) to pull in your git repository and automatically mark it as a development egg:

```
[buildout]
extensions = mr.developer
auto-checkout = package.name

[sources]
package.name = git url/to/package.name.git
```

With this setup, mr.developer will automatically check out the git repository to the `src/` subdirectory and add that to the buildout `develop` option.

## Using a tarball download

Places like github.com also offer an option to download a tarball with the current contents of the repository. You could use that to load that tarball as an egg source with the `find-links` option:

```
[buildout]
find-links = http://github.com/yourname/package.name/tarball/version#egg=package.name-versionnumber
eggs = package.name
```

Buildout will then use that specific `find-links` entry to find the egg, provided it cannot find the egg elsewhere.

Comment: I think the first alternative might actually suit my needs well enough, as I could just check out the project right inside the installation directory. I'm going to give it a go. I had some trouble with the develop option earlier though, as Buildout still complained about not finding my distribution at PyPI.

Comment: @aknuds1: There is a [talk on using buildout for package development](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/buildout/) that may contain additional hints.

Comment: Your first buildout.cfg is not sufficient. Buildout requires a [parts] section in buildout.cfg: 'Error: Missing option: buildout:parts'.

Comment: @aknuds1: all the examples are only showing the options pertaining to the specific technique and are not complete buildout.cfg files. See the talk I linked to for further details on the use of buildout.

Comment: Nota Bene: it is `extensions` and not `extension` in the `[buildout]` section !!! (cf https://github.com/fschulze/mr.developer#usage)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I read your page, I miss the information you gave as an answer in stackoverflow about the option to pin it to a specific version (so no need for the newest = false) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402774/how-to-pin-version-of-recipe-egg-for-a-particular-part

Comment: Develop eggs are used regardless of version pins.

Answer (score 3):

You easily use Buildout with checkouts from repository by either using the *develop* directive of zc.buildout or using the mr.developer buildout extension where you can define the packages to be checkout directly from a given repository URL (supports git, svn and others version control systems).

See

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer

Comment: The develop directive would install a development egg of my distribution though, am I right? I want to install a regular, not development, egg. It looks like mr.developer might be what I need; I looked at it before, but I figured it had to be overkill for my simple case. Maybe it isn't after all.. I'll give it a go and see if it does what I need.