# How to pin version of recipe egg for a particular part

Tags: buildout

I have added a section in my buildout to install python-ldap as described here:

http://bluedynamics.com/articles/jens/python-ldap-as-egg-with-buildout

However my buildout fails with:

```
While:
  Initializing.
  Getting section buildout.
  Initializing section buildout.
  Getting option buildout:eggs.
  Getting section python-ldap.
  Initializing section python-ldap.
  Installing recipe zc.recipe.egg.
 Error: There is a version conflict.
We already have: zc.buildout 1.4.2
but zc.recipe.egg 1.3.2 requires 'zc.buildout>=1.5.0'.
```

Why is buildout trying to get the latest version of zc.recipe.egg for this particular part even though it is pinned to 1.2.2 in the versions para?

Comment: Moving the egg from buildout to instance fixed the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the exact same problem, and solved it by uninstalling the python-zc.buildout Debian package which was installed on my machine with version 1.4.3.

Answer (score 3):

You can pin any and all eggs (regardless of what they are used for) with a `versions` section. You have to explicitly declare such a section, but then it applies to recipe eggs as well:

```
[buildout]
... # Other options in the buildout section omitted
versions = versions

[versions]
zc.recipe.egg = 1.2.2
```

You can name the part that specifies version pins any way you want, but most people just name it `versions`.

Comment: That's what I have (straight from the Plone buildout). But it does not seem to work. Could it be because I am using the :custom recipe rather than the plain zc.recipe.egg?

Comment: No. Try running `bin/buildout -vvvv` for more detail about why this might be happening.

Comment: Added -vvvv. Does not add anything else to my original output. Which leads me to think that it does not process the "versions" line at all.  My buildout is here: http://pastebin.com/8hFr8qaU

Comment: I got this working. Not sure why it works now.

1) I moved the egg from the buildout:eggs section to the instance:eggs section.

2) I changed the recipe to zc.recipe.egg:develop rather than :custom

3) I included the source of python-ldap in the src directory and wrote a script to massage the config.cfg file there