# Fail to run buildout to upgrade plone from 4.2.4 to 4.3

Tags: plone, upgrade, buildout

Debian 6.
After modified extents and commented out all in [version] in buildout.cfg, "buildout -vvv" shows:

```
Installing 'buildout.dumppickedversions'.
We have the distribution that satisfies 'buildout.dumppickedversions==0.5'.
Installing 'plone.recipe.zeoserver'.
We have the distribution that satisfies 'plone.recipe.zeoserver==1.2.6'.
Getting required 'ZopeUndo==2.12.0'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'ZopeUndo==2.12.0'.
Getting required 'ZODB3==3.10.5'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'ZODB3==3.10.5'.
Getting required 'zope.mkzeoinstance==3.9.5'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.mkzeoinstance==3.9.5'.
Getting required 'zc.recipe.egg==1.3.2'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zc.recipe.egg==1.3.2'.
Getting required 'zope.interface==3.6.7'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.interface==3.6.7'.
Getting required 'zope.event==3.5.2'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.event==3.5.2'.
Getting required 'zdaemon==2.0.7'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zdaemon==2.0.7'.
Getting required 'ZConfig==2.9.1'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'ZConfig==2.9.1'.
Getting required 'zc.lockfile==1.0.2'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zc.lockfile==1.0.2'.
Getting required 'transaction==1.1.1'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'transaction==1.1.1'.
Could't load zc.buildout entry point default
from plone.recipe.zeoserver:
There is a version conflict.
We already have: zc.buildout 1.4.4
but zc.recipe.egg 1.3.2 requires 'zc.buildout>=1.5.0'..
While:
  Installing.
  Getting section zeoserver.
  Initializing section zeoserver.
  Installing recipe plone.recipe.zeoserver.
Error: There is a version conflict.
We already have: zc.buildout 1.4.4
but zc.recipe.egg 1.3.2 requires 'zc.buildout>=1.5.0'.
*************** PICKED VERSIONS ****************
[versions]

*************** /PICKED VERSIONS ***************
```

I found a related [question]:[How to pin version of recipe egg for a particular part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402774/how-to-pin-version-of-recipe-egg-for-a-particular-part), but it does not work for me.

Best regards.
Hugo

Comment: Try `python bootstrap.py -v 1.7` and run buildout, run.

Comment: What add-ons are you using, any other buildout-config-customz? Where you using Unified-Installer/can you provide your config(s)? Do you know, how to figure out, which deps are pinned of which prod? (I think Mikko provided a nice solution for this somewhere)

Comment: Without seeing your buildout, it is difficult to answer, but make sure that you pin both zc.recipe.egg and zc.buildout to mutually compatible version numbers (such as 1.3.2 and 1.5.2, respectively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are experiencing too much trouble, a good approach can be, to build a new instance with the new version, add eggs and other special config-extensions you did, and then move the data (ZODB+BLOBs) of the old instance to the new one.