# Plone Upgrade - 4.0.5 to current?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have a Plone 4.0.5 install running on Ubuntu 12.04.

I want to update to the latest release as I assume that keeping up to date is best practice (in other words there's no new functionality or defect-resolutions which I'm looking to get).

The Plone page says : http://plone.org/documentation/faq/upgrade-plone which points at http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide for this type of upgrade but the resulting links don't actually explain how to do anything other the edge cases.

I'm interested how to do this and would be particularly interested to know whether I can do it in one jump.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541532/fail-to-run-buildout-to-upgrade-plone-from-4-2-4-to-4-3 help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading a plain Plone Site works well.

Of course the best practice is to create a full backup of your site, or create a second installation where you can perform the update first. If everything goes well you can upgrade your LIVE site.

I guess you have some packages installed from the collective or other sources. 
Then you have to check if the particular package is Plone 4.3.2 ready. On well maintained packages you can get the needed information from pypi (further: CI server, github, etc.).
You need to pin the required versions in your buildout manually.

Upgrading from Plone 4.0.x to 4.3 mainly addresses some deprecated imports (moved modules) and the by default disabled jQuery integration (jq instead of $). 
Those two points are the main reason why some upgrades in my case did not work well.

To make sure your 3rd party packages are ready for Plone 4.3 you can use the [`collective.ploneupgradecheck`](https://github.com/jone/collective.ploneupgradecheck) (Also clone the source of the package you want to check)

Comment: OK thanks. I think I might try the "create a second installation first" approach .